# How to hide the pagination bar if the number of pages is less than the number of items per page in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to hide the pagination bar when the number of pages to render is smaller than the number of items per page. I tried with ng-show but it didn't work.

```
        <tr ng-repeat="row in allItems">
                    <td>{{ row.Name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ row.Email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ row.Phone }}</td>
                </tr>
          </tbody>
        <tfoot ng-show="allItems.length > itemsPerPage">
                <tr>                
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>   

                    <td st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="itemsPerPage" st-template="/example/pagination.html" >
                    </td>

                </tr>
       </tfoot>
```

Comment: The code we can see looks fine so perhaps the controller values are not what you think they are.  Try logging them to the console.  Does `$scope.itemsPerPage` exist and have the expected value in the console?  Same question for `allItems`.

Comment: @sh0ber they both exist and they have the expected value

Answer (score 0):

try putting brackets around the condition, like `ng-show="(allItems.length>itemsPerPage)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I referred to the wrong label. This is how I defined my table:

```
<table id = "table"  st-safe-src="data" st-table="allItems">
```

and when I tried to hide the table footer I should've written:

```
<tfoot ng-show="data.length > itemsPerPage">
```